# How to set image section size of optical flow?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, opticalflow

I am trying find optical flow vector using the Lucas-Kanade method using MATLAB inbuilt function `opticalflowlk`, in this method we need to divide each image into smaller section of given window size. 
By using inbuilt `opticalflowlk` method I am not able to find how can I set window size for that. If it is not possible then what is the default window size is used by `opticalflowlk`? I have read all documentation but didn't find the answer.

Comment: LK Method solves the basic optical flow equations for all the pixels in that neighborhood by the least squares criterion. The least-squares approach implicitly assumes that the errors in the image data have a Gaussian distribution with zero mean. So in this case the window size is always constant and will never change. If you have a large-scale image and want to reduce them, LK can still be applied on the reduced-scale images. But better method to use is the Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi (KLT).

Comment: You can also type `edit opticalFlowLK` in MATLAB Command Window, and trace the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @OsamaAbbas for your response.

Comment: You are welcome, and good luck

Comment: @OsamaAbbas do you know why Lucas kanade algorithm taking too much processing time when i implemented as compare to using inbuilt method opticalFlowK  in matlab?  Here is implementation code link of matlab:- https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48744-lucas-kanade-tutorial-example-1/content/LucasKanadeExample1/html/LKExample1.html

Comment: Depends on many factors. Image size is an important factor to consider when applying LK implemented method; not builtin method. Also the quality. And finally the commands you're using. Some commands take time to be interpreted. If you want to calculate the time of processing you can use `tic toc` commands.